# How Can I call 2 different function using one toggle button in vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, toggle, annyang

I am Using annyang.js for speech-recognition which have 2 different functions, for start `annyang.start()` and for stop `annyang.abort()`
Now how do i make a toggle button which will fire both of these functions?

my code

```
<div class="action" onclick="actionToogle()">
```

JS

```
<script>
    function actionToogle() {
      var action = document.querySelector(".action");
      action.classList.toggle("active",annyang.start());
    }
  </script>
```

currently its just starting the recognition by  `annyang.start()` ,
but i want whenever i click the button the recognition will be stop by `annyang.abort()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check if action has active class you can start or if it doesnt have you can stop.

```
function actionToogle() {
  var action = document.querySelector(".action");
  action.classList.toggle("active");
  
  if (action.classList.contains("active")) {
    // annyang.start();
    console.log("Started");
  } else {
    // annyang.abort();
    console.log("Stopped");
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you so so so much :) , it worked 100% as I expected, thanks again :)